# UIpageViewController start with first page in horizontal mode?

Tags: ios, customization, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to customize the `UIPageViewController` which should only first page 
(say label 1) in horizontal mode and after moving to next page its should show both page (label 2 and 3) side by side.It should show only first page when launches first time. It's kind of photoallbum book. any idea?

**Note** : Please don't down the question if you not clear.Please let me know.

Comment: I did something similar recently. I passed an empty view controller at index zero and the real first page at index 1 so that it looks better that way.

Comment: cool, i will try and will update you.You must get credit then.Thanks

Comment: @zen any sample code?

Comment: can we hide the first view ?

Comment: hey can u add your comments in ans  so that i can vote up you ? I have solved by hiding the first view and last view , i did not add any empty view but you gave me the idea of doing so.